# How to use std::ref?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

What is the correct way to use `std::ref`? I tried following code in VS2010 and it doesn't compile:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
struct IsEven
{
    bool operator()(int n) 
    {
        if(n % 2 == 0)
        {
            evens.push_back(n);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    vector<int> evens;
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    IsEven f;
    vector<int>::iterator newEnd = remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ref(f));
    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\xxresult(28): error C2903: 'result' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template
>
> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\xxresult(28): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

Plus some more...

Comment: It compiles with g++ (both 4.6 and 4.8).

Comment: @nabulke: even in C++11? I thought this should work..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a bug or set of bugs in Visual C++ 10.0 implementation of `std::ref`.

It has reportedly been fixed for Visual C++ 11; see my [earlier question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500588/visual-c-10-0-bug-in-stdreference-wrapper).

STL at Microsoft answered thusly: "We've already fixed it, and the fix will be available in VC11 RTM. (However, the fix didn't get into the VC11 Beta.)"

Answer (score 4):

I recieved the same compilation error with VS2010 and corrected it by inheriting from `std::unary_function`:

```
struct IsEven : std::unary_function<int, bool>
```

I only considered this due to `result` appearing in the error message. I can only guess that `std::ref`, in VS2010, depends on the `typedef`s in `unary_function`:

```
template <class Arg, class Result>
  struct unary_function {
    typedef Arg argument_type;
    typedef Result result_type;
  };
```

EDIT:

See answer from [Cheers and hth. - Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) regarding bug in VS2010.

Comment: This should not be necessary anymore. File a bug.