# Why does assigning std::ref not change the value of the referenced object?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference-wrapper

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int xx = 7;

template<class T>
void f1(T arg)
{
    arg += xx;
}

template<class T>
void f2(T arg)
{
    arg = xx;
}

int main()
{
    int j;

    j=100;
    f1(std::ref(j));
    std::cout << j << std::endl;

    j=100;
    f2(std::ref(j));
    std::cout << j << std::endl;
}
```

When executed, this code outputs

```
107
100
```

I would have expected the second value to be 7 rather than 100.

What am I missing?

Comment: The reference wrapper is reseatable, so assigning changes what's referenced, not the referred object.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A small modification to `f2` provides the clue:

```
template<class T>
void f2(T arg)
{
    arg.get() = xx;
}
```

This now does what you expect.

This has happened because `std::ref` returns a `std::reference_wrapper<>` object. The assignment operator of which *rebinds* the wrapper.
(see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%3D)

It does not make an assignment to the wrapped reference.

In the `f1` case, all is working as you expected because a `std::reference_wrapper<T>` provides a conversion operator to `T&`, which will bind to the implicit right hand side of `int`s implicit `operator+`.

Comment: Do you need a job ?

Answer (score 12):

`reference_wrapper` has `operator =` and a non explicit constructor, see [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

So, even if it is surprising, it is the normal behaviour:

`f2` rebinds the local reference_wrapper to `xx`.

Answer (score 11):

> `arg = xx;`

Local `arg` now refers to (read as binds with) `xx`. (And no more refers to `j`)

> `arg += xx;`

Implicit `operator T& ()` is applied to match the argument of `operator +=` and hence addition is performed on referred object i.e. `j`.

So the observed behaviour is correct.